# vmware + visual studio 2013 kernel debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, kernel, vmware

To develop window driver I make vs 2013 + vmware debugging environment.
My pc spec is good.
When i use win7 normally in vmware, it's performance is good.
But once i start debugging, it show very bad performance in vmware, not host pc.  Host pc is not bad.
Even I can't make folder in foreground of vmware.

I also use virtualKD + pure windbg.  It's same...

My processor is i5, and ram is 8G.  I allocate 2 processor and 2G to vmware.

Why is debugging performace very bad?

I must develop driver within a few day...  I have no time.

Comment: I bechmark vmware.  Memory is 45% when i allocate 3g.  CPU utilization is 100%... Why is cpu so high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, 2GB isn't enough RAM. Give at least 4.